# How to get last array element's specific value in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, codeigniter

I am integrating multi step form in php and i have list of questions (in array) using loop
and i want "submit" button should show in last question,Means for example if there is 5 questions
( fetching from database) then whenever last question comes then there should be "submit" button instead of
"next",My code not working if last question is "ISSubQuestion",showing me "submit" button on first question instead of last question (use can see only one subquestion out of two) How can i do this ?
Here is my array,Where i am wrong ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [question] => Lorem Ipsum1.
            [ques_id] => 0
            [IsRatingQuestion] => 0
            [ISSubQuestion] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [question] => Lorem Ipsum2.
            [IsRatingQuestion] => 1
            [ISSubQuestion] => 
       )

    [2] => Array
        (
           [question] => Lorem Ipsum3.
           [IsRatingQuestion] => 
            [ISSubQuestion] => 1
        )
)
```

Here is php code

```
//$rec containing array values ( coming from database)
foreach($rec as $key => $records)
    { 
                $record_last_end = $rec;
                $lastElement = array_key_last($record_last_end);
                $lastarray = array_values(array_slice($rec, -1))[0];
                if($key == $lastElement)
                { 
                
                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="next action-button" >  
                <?php } else { ?>   
                
                <input type="button" name="next" id="next1" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                <?php }  ?> 
    }
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions provided help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple solution that does not use any extra functions or iterations. You can simply add a counter `$i` and increment it with each loop.

In each loop you check if the value of `$i == count($array)`. A true condition would be the last element of the array.

```php
$rec = array(
    0 => array(
        'question' => 'Lorem Ipsum1.',
        'ques_id' => 0,
        'IsRatingQuestion' => 0,
        'ISSubQuestion' => ''
    ),

    1 => array(
        'question' => 'Lorem Ipsum2.',
        'IsRatingQuestion' => 1,
        'ISSubQuestion' => ''
    ),

    2 => array(
        'question' => 'Lorem Ipsum3.',
        'IsRatingQuestion' => '',
        'ISSubQuestion' => 1
    )
);

$i = 0;
$arrayCount = count($rec);
foreach ($rec as $records) {
    $i++;
    print_r($records);
    if ($i == $arrayCount) {
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="submit" class="next action-button">
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <input type="button" name="next" id="next1" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
        <?php
    }
}
```

A working example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f2bb50efd4cc17ecb33e5bf5843a1df213a23ba

Comment: The `print_r($records)` is only there to show the output in combination with the array values. In real world you would delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manipulating your array after getting it from database? try this:

```
$record_last_end = array_values($rec);

$lastElement = array_key_last( $record_last_end);

$lastarray = array_slice($record_last_end , -1)[0];

foreach($record_last_end as $key => $records)
    {                
                if($key == $lastElement)
                { 
                
                ?>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="next action-button" >  
                <?php } else { ?>   
                
                <input type="button" name="next" id="next1" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
                <?php }  ?> 
    }
```

Comment: change foreach($rec as $key => $records) to foreach($record_last_end as $key => $records)